# Setting scope on a radio button value doesn't allow for filtering in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I've followed the documentation for using ng-model on radio buttons to set the value when selected. However, I am using a filter. When I set

$scope.career on line 93 of my Plunker it will not allow me to filter by those values. If I don't set a default value on the mode it filters fine. I wanted to set the first one to the default, so a search would be by Undergraduate.

http://plnkr.co/edit/HgCG9XGP2Ec0z6FopxRl?p=preview

I would suggest a search on a subject such as "Accounting" to see the filter work.

Here is a second plunker with the line uncommented. This one doesn't filter down when you click the radio buttons after searching.

http://plnkr.co/edit/PvOqJyEVRVyKz3ZbJW2Z

Even if I put a watch on each of the radio buttons and set the scope, the filter still doesn't work when it is set. Does anyone know why this doesn't work when you preset a radio button?

Comment: works fine for me when set default and do a search...not clear what problem is

Comment: On the second link, when you click it search for "Accounting". You should get 6 results. If you click Graduate, it should pare it down to two entries. It works for me on the first link I created, but not on the second plunker when I preset the value for Undergraduate.

Comment: This may not be the direct cause, but in your code, `my_json` is global variable.  Are you sure this is what you want?  I suggest using `ngResource` to clean up your service code.